# How to store and restore the current font size?

Tags: macros, fontsize

In relation with this example: [New command without brackets inside new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423186/new-command-without-brackets-inside-new-environment), I have to pass the current font size to the environment, but I prefer it takes it by itself?

To make it clear, I would like to store the `selectfont` parameters and reuse them later.

There is an obvious bracket solution, but the OP of the related question doesn't want to use brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Bla

\item{\small Small is small} 

\item Bla is not small, but the OP of the related question doesn't want to use brackets.

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I then try to make a switch system inside the `\item` macro and for this I have to know what are the fontsize parameters, to store and restore them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{paralist,xparse}

\newcommand{\Com}[1][\hspace{1cm}]{\item[#1\aftergroup\footnotesize]}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Itemize}
    {O{}    % item caracter ex $\bullet$
    D<>{\normalsize}}{%
    \begin{list}{#2#1\aftergroup#2}{%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0em} % adapt as you want
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{5pt}%
    }}{%
    \end{list}}


\begin{document}

\large

\begin{Itemize}[$\bullet$]<\large>
\item One
\item Two
\Com This is my comment
\item Three
\Com This is my comment
\end{Itemize}

Back to current font size !

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc

Comment: @Christian Hupfer did you see my edit ?

Comment: @Tarass: You edited your question after closing, now it's going to the reopen queue...

Comment: It is written that I have to edit and explain, so did I ;-)

Comment: Your edit should aim to explain why this isn't a duplicate of the indicated question (if you think it isn't).  But if you just need to reset to the original font size, that's a different matter (that you really should have explained originally).  In that case, I believe that changing the font size within the new environment should mean that the font will automatically change back afterward.

Comment: @Teepeemm The font size switch several times inside the environment, I have to swicth between small or footnotesize and the current size as it explain in the related question.

Comment: `\makeatletter\newcommand{\savefont}{\xdef\oldfontsize{\f@size}\xdef\oldblskip{\baselineskip}}
    \newcommand{\backtoppevfont}{\fontsize{\oldfontsize}{\oldblskip}}
    \makeatother` and use them at the begining and end of the environment

Comment: I really appriciate your kindness. It works perfectly with a final `\selectfont`. Consider to write an answer, I never saw your answer elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the duplicate of the answer if reopened to be re-closed :P https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322256/what-is-the-second-value-in-fontsize-for. Welcome!

Comment: The question needs to be reopened before it can be answered. Also, the second parameter of \fontsize is stored in f@baselineskip (you probably won't need this since you already have an answer, but it is good to know).

Comment: @koleygr What you wrote is not on the page you linked, I do not see it.

Comment: @Circumscribe It could be usefull for someone else.

Comment: At the moment I answered the edited question had the phrase: "More exactly : how to find the second paramater of \fontsize{...}{...}selectfont ?parameters and reuse them latter.". So, this is why I made the above comment... Of course This is not the full answer given there... but the most of the people will find this instead if looking for that... Any way, already voted to reopen.

Comment: I rephrase the title of my question in a more explicit way. I didn't know where it will lead at the first time, the precision came with the comments.

Comment: Why do you even need this? The font sizes are changing back to the previous size, don't they?

Comment: may be deleting the word "parameters" from the title would make it more helpful (explanation: Even people that are not aware of `\fontsize` command would find it earier. May be spliting the word fontsize would be nice too for the same reason)

Comment: @Skillmon Look, please, to my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423186/new-command-without-brackets-inside-new-environment/423216?noredirect=1#comment1058949_423216, you will see that I have to switch the font size. The problem is not at the end of the enviroment but in the switches. If you have a better idea to to answer this question, I am interested to learn.

Comment: @koleygr I am not very good at english and not very aware of howto ask a question with the right way. Please, fill free (you or someone else) to rephrase what is needed to make it usefull. On my side I have my answer and I can even delete the question, but i still think it could be usefull.

Comment: @Tarass, I am not good in English too. Just suggested because I know how people are googling or are supposed to google... I used many times this for  some reasons and also think that it is useful (even as a closed question). By the way I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308872/saving-and-restoring-font-settings And may have to answer there as an alternative answer...

Comment: @koleygr I made an edit following your suggestion and taking account of the brackets solution you are pointing.

Comment: You could as well do some nasty argument grabbing and only assign the size for `\Com` locally. But I guess that wouldn't be very robust (though I've wrote something which works with your MWE) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}


%This is my suggestion (with @Circumscribe's comment in account):

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savefont}{\xdef\oldfontsize{\f@size}\xdef\oldblskip{\f@baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\backtoppevfont}{\fontsize{\oldfontsize}{\oldblskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother


%Just added to demonstrate "unknown" font
\def\randomSize{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{random(1,4)}%
\foreach \fnt[count=\i from 1] in {\tiny,\footnotesize,\large,\Large}{%
\ifnum \a=\i\global\let\fs\fnt\breakforeach
\fi}\expandafter\string\fs\fs%
}
\begin{document}


Here is a text... and a random change of font to:\randomSize'' Test! RFont \savefont

That turned into \small\verb|\small| here and restored to \backtoppevfont RFont1!

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: An alternative solution: 
`{\tiny Text in tiny font.} Now a text in normal font.`
[Credits](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6268)

Answer (score 3):

Save the current font and add some code to `\item` so the font is restored after issuing the needed `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % mock text

\newif\ifcomment
\newcommand{\Com}{\par\footnotesize\itshape\commenttrue}

\newenvironment{Itemize}
 {%
  \edef\Itemizecurrent{\the\font}%
  \itemize
  \preto{\item}{\ifcomment\par\Itemizecurrent\fi}%
 }{%
   \enditemize
 }


\begin{document}

\begin{Itemize}
\item One
\item \lipsum[4]
\Com \lipsum[5]
\item Three
\Com This is my comment
\end{Itemize}

Back to current font size!

\end{document}
```

[image]